# iPhone MKMapView

Tags: iphone, mkmapview

I have a problem while running the application in the background, I have allocated `mapview` and released all the objects and while running the app in the background getting the following error:

> void -[MKTileCache synchronize](MKTileCache*, objc_selector*) called while in background! and 
>   program terminates, have set True in info.plist, application did enter background,

Comment: Your question is not clear enough yet. Please edit your question and add some more details. For instance, do you expect your app to keep on running in the background, or not?

Comment: Yes i want the app to be run in the background,however when i press home button it call one of the webservices,get response latitude and longitude and after that it crashes

Answer (score 0):

See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW1

particularly the section "Being a Responsible, Multitasking-Aware Application".

I think you should stop updating your views on location updates when in the background. `MKMapView` might be an exception to the rule that view manipulation is allowed.